# Httpd Auth login restriction

Tags: httpd

I have problem with Authorization in httpd.
when I connect to http:/user1
the login screen pop up and user1,user2 can login and show the user1's data.
how can I create a rule that user1 can only browse user1 folder, and other users can only login to their own folder ? thanks

User list in home folder
/home/user1
/home/user2

### vi /etc/httpd/.htpasswd

user1:$apr1$NWoTku5D$frFdpU6Y9eoZ4y1KZVGa60
user2:5D$frFdpU6Y9eoZ4y1KZVGa60$apr1$NWoTku

---

### vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig
AuthType basic
AuthName "Media Zone"
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have put that for the default Document Root that is /var/www in Debian/Ubuntu based servers and /var/www/html for redhat/centos.

You have to make multiple virtual hosts

make one for user1 for example in /var/www/html/user1 
make other for user2      in   /var/www/html/user2

Create different .htpasswd file for each user and put that in the Virtual host file accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be an `index.php` where you can query `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`. Depending on the name you could redirect to different static pages or just build dynamic pages suited for the user.